# Application Loader getting stuck while uploading package to App Store

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am trying upload to my app to iTunes connect using Application Loader. Many times I have done this, but this time strangely while uploading it is getting stuck at, `upload` process

[image]

My app is of 14MB, upto 3MB it processed, after that its showing above screen. While searching about this, many were faced issue in authentication stuck, but here its authenticated, but in the middle of package upload it is getting stuck. I developed this app using Xamarin.Forms

Did anyone know reason for this? Its getting stopped abruptly in the middle again resuming like this its uploaded two build. Can I publish that build, whether it would have properly uploaded or not?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Application Loader and Xcode? After a binary is uploaded and it's completed the "Processing" phase in iTunes Connect, you should get an email saying it's ready to be used. I would guess it's OK to upload at that point if it processed OK.

Comment: I used 7.1.1 & 7.3 Xcode and its corresponding Application Loader, in both it behaved same way only. Till now I didn't find why it happened like that, but somehow it uploaded binary in iTunes Connect and now my app also approved, next time while uploading I hope that this shouldn't happen, hence eager to find solution for this.

Comment: i used 8.1 Xcode and it's Application loader, still not got any success. i also had changed HTTPPROXY port to 80.